# Does it cost gas to cancel a transaction? Can I replace / speed up the transaction to just 1 gwei then cancel to reduce fees?

Tags: gas-price, gas-refund, cancel-transaction

My transaction is stuck, but can I speed it up by replacing the fee with 1 gwei then cancel it to reduce the fees to cancel?

I tried to cancel and speed up but its still stuck. I check etherscan and it says the transaction is waiting on a previous one first. But I checked the previous transaction and it says its confirmed already. I even tried to pump up the fee higher, but still didnt confirm. Which is now I want to just cancel it all together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to "cancel" a transaction is to "replace" it with another transaction.

Wallets replace transactions by sending a transfer to itself. The cheapest ether transfer uses 21000 gas and you have to increase `gasPrice` more than 10%.

Comment: so every time you replace a transaction it needs to be upped by 10% more gas? no way to replace the transaction with a lower gas setting?

Comment: @Patoshiパトシ Yes, that is about right. Under the protocol there's no explicit rule but geth requires a 10% increase and most miners use the default settings. You could try to bribe a miner to accept less.